# Tools or scripts to scrape browser credentials and data?

Tags: web-browser, exploit, forensics

I'm exploiting machines in a network and I'm currently trying to scrape data to further my testing from the compromised machines. There's no SOE build so i've got a variety of different environments.

I'm looking for any scripts like [this](http://www.rapid7.com/db/modules/post/windows/gather/enum_ie) or [this](http://www.rapid7.com/db/modules/post/multi/gather/firefox_creds) (metasploit modules for IE and Firefox respectively) that can scrape both Chrome and Safari browser data in a similar fashion (Cookies and Credentials databases and output via command-line..).

I don't mind if the tool is standalone like this [this one](http://securityxploded.com/chromepassworddecryptor.php) (ChromePasswordDecryptor) but this specific tool has failed to recover passwords for me (the credentials database on the target systems are protected by the local user password as well as described [here](http://thehackernews.com/2013/12/Master-Password-Google-Chrome.html) and it doesn't ask for authentication during remote extraction.

Edit:
I've also found [this tool](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/opera_password_recovery.html) for Opera and these tools which shows chrome's [cache](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/chrome_cache_view.html) and [history](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/chrome_history_view.html), but the chrome tool still doesn't appear to extract credential databases

Comment: I should add i'm not opposed to creating my own script, I just don't like doubling up on the effort. I'm also not so sure how/where the passwords are stored in the chrome environment (unlike the Firefox env where lots of people have written useful information regarding the password stores...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've already listed some resources so I will [add another](http://raidersec.blogspot.com/2013/06/how-browsers-store-your-passwords-and.html) that is not a tool per-se, but a write up on how the different browsers are storing data. The write up contains a minimal python script that should help get you started. As for Safari, pre version 6.0 the credentials [were only base64 encoded](https://community.rapid7.com/community/metasploit/blog/2013/12/26/apple-safari-makes-password-stealing-fun-and-easy-yes-please) so it was easier to [get data then](http://securelist.com/blog/incidents/58188/loophole-in-safari/). The difference with Safari (OSX for that matter) is that, Safari uses keychains at times (I say at times because you don't have to use it), in which you'll need to [attack/analyze the keychain](https://github.com/juuso/keychaindump). There are a lot of [tools available for analyzing/breaking](http://blog.opensecurityresearch.com/2013/08/analyzing-keychain-contents-with.html) this as well.

As for an all inclusive tool, I personally haven't seen one but I will urge to you check some forensics based sites before pentesting sites. The reasoning for this is, when performing forensics work, many of these applications need to be analyzed (browser data) so it's not uncommon to find tools that have modules (EnScripts for example) that do this from one single point.

Comment: Thanks, the  first link there is definitely helpful, I was looking at this (http://www.forensicswiki.org/wiki/Google_Chrome) site but while there's plenty of detail on all the other data, theres none on the passwords.